Город (plural form)
Why does город become города when it's plural? Isn't it supposed to be городы?
Thank you.

It was indeed городы up until early XIX century, and before that it used to be городи.
In Old Russian, there were three grammatical numbers: the singular, the plural, and the dual, the latter was used to mark pairs of objects. The nominative of the word for "city" or "town" was городъ in the singular, города in the dual, and городи in the plural.
Later, the dual number died out, but left its traces in the declension paradigms of the words for things that naturally come in pairs: глаза́, бока́, рога́ etc.
Even later, the old plural nominative forms ending in и got replaced with what used to be accusative forms in ы: городи had become городы and so on. The old nominative ending survived in a handful of words: соседи, черти, они, одни, сами.
Later still, Russian had developed a tendency to use the form in -а (the remnant of the old dual) to form the nominative plural for the words for things that don't come in pairs: города́, поезда́, вечера́, and even for the words that didn't exist when the dual number had been a thing: доктора́, буфера́, паспорта́ etc. All these words used the ending ы in the past.
The number of nouns in а in the nominative plural is growing even now, and forms like договора́, центра́, кителя́, etc., that were considered poor style as late as fifty years ago, are gradually becoming a variant of the norm. Usually, these forms start out in professional argots and then get picked up by the mainstream language.

Колена is not dual; it is the normal expected plural for "tribes" and "bends in a river". The old neuter dual is колени, used for "knees", of which we all only have two. And then there is the plural коленья for a join or node in tubes. I think this third one is relatively rare. Maybe most people say колена for that too?

@pompey1969: the dual nominative for колѣно was колѣнѣ (with колѣни as a possible variant), the plural nominative колѣна. The traces of the old dual are what I said, traces, e.g. the word глаз was not even a thing when the dual was still being used.

Are юга́/севера́ the norm now?

@DimitriVulis: not according to any dictionary I could find, but for as long as the plural forms have been a thing at all, albeit colloquial, they were being formed using the pattern in -а
